# Iterating through JSON structure matching criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

I have a JSON structure that looks like this...

```
[
    [{
        "timeBucket": 1472058000000,
        "errors": 534,
        "errorFree": 0,
        "business": 0,
        "errorRate": 1.0,
        "breakdown": [{
            "type": "newview",
            "count": 359,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }, {
            "type": "oldview",
            "count": 169,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }, {
            "type": "noview",
            "count": 6,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }]
    }],
    [{
        "timeBucket": 1472061600000,
        "errors": 537,
        "errorFree": 0,
        "business": 0,
        "errorRate": 1.0,
        "breakdown": [{
            "type": "newview",
            "count": 338,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }, {
            "type": "oldview",
            "count": 184,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }, {
            "type": "noview",
            "count": 14,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }, {
            "type": "someview",
            "count": 1,
            "errorRate": 1.0
        }]
    }]
]
```

This is for highcharts, so to get at the timeBucket and errors values, I use this ( and it works great thanks to the community here so thank you, thank you, thank you).

```
            Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
                for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                   options.series[0].data.push(
                        [p[i].timeBucket, parseFloat(p[i].errors)
                   );
                }
            });
```

What I'm trying to get at now is the "count" value in "breakdown" where type == "newview"
I thought it would be like this but I'm wrong....

```
                Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                       options.series[0].data.push(
                            [p[i].timeBucket, parseFloat(p[i].breakdown[0].type["newview"].count)
                       );
                    }
                });
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can easily solve this? Many many thanks!

Comment: This was confusing me since you have a loop to iterate over an array that consistently has only one member. Anyway, keeping that in place, since every `breakdown[0]` has `.type == "newview"`, wouldn't you just need to do this instead? `parseFloat(p[i].breakdown[0].count)`

Answer (score 0):

Can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var nViewCount = p[i].breakdown.reduce(function(a,c){
   return c.type === "newview" ? c.count : a;
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function:

```
function find(breakdown,typeValue){
   var len = breakdown.length;
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(breakdown[i].type=="typeValue"){
          return breakdown[i].count
      }
    }
}

Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
                for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                   options.series[0].data.push(
                        [p[i].timeBucket, parseFloat(find(p[i].breakdown,"newview"))
                   );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on each breakdown element to select only the element of your interest:

```
var count = p[i].breakdown.filter(function(ele, idx) {
    return ele.type == "newview";
})[0];
count = (count === undefined) ? 0 : +count.count
```

My example:

```js
var myData = [
  [{
    "timeBucket": 1472058000000,
    "errors": 534,
    "errorFree": 0,
    "business": 0,
    "errorRate": 1.0,
    "breakdown": [{
      "type": "newview",
      "count": 359,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }, {
      "type": "oldview",
      "count": 169,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }, {
      "type": "noview",
      "count": 6,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }]
  }],
  [{
    "timeBucket": 1472061600000,
    "errors": 537,
    "errorFree": 0,
    "business": 0,
    "errorRate": 1.0,
    "breakdown": [{
      "type": "newview",
      "count": 338,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }, {
      "type": "oldview",
      "count": 184,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }, {
      "type": "noview",
      "count": 14,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }, {
      "type": "someview",
      "count": 1,
      "errorRate": 1.0
    }]
  }]
];
var result = [];

myData.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
  var count = ele[0].breakdown.filter(function(ele, idx) {
    return ele.type == "newview";
  })[0];
  count = (count === undefined) ? 0 : +count.count
  result.push(
    [ele[0].timeBucket, parseFloat(ele[0].errors), count]);
});

console.log(result);
```